# Power Automate Flow to upload file to scm?We h

Tags: azure, automation, power-automate

I am working on Power Automate Flow that basically is trying to upload a file to an Azure Web App.

As the Azure Web App uses DevOps for CI, it uploads those files to the SCM, but I can only get my Flow to upload to the FTP, which doesn't get used.

Any ideas on how I can connect my flow to upload a file to the SCM filemanager?

Comment: The easiest way is to upload your files using the KUDU console. To access the console navigate to `https://<yoursite>.scm.azurewebsites.net` where `<yoursite>` is the name of your App.

In the Kudu console, click on the Debug Console tab, then on PowerShell. That will open a file browser where you can navigate to your directory and upload the files. You could check whether you can invoke KUDU REST api in your Power Automate Flow.

Comment: Thanks for this - I managed to work around it, by changing my pipeline to use v3 so it doesnt use the virtual directory and read from a zip file. Now I can see my files through FTP, meaning my flow now works :). Thanks for the answer though!